# count xml tag from HTTPService.lastresult in flex 3

Tags: xml, apache-flex, count, flex3, httpservice

I have a PHP file echoing the following XML:

```
header("content-type:xml-text");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages>
    <page>
        <user>1</user>
        <name>book1</name>
        <theme>mariage</theme>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>25</height>
        <images>
            <image>image1.jpg</image>
            <image>image2.jpg</image>
            <image>image3.jpg</image>
            <image>image4.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </page>
</pages>';
```

i'm using flex **HTTPService** to get the the xml file and i need to count the number of images in it (4 in this particular case).

I've used the following code and it show 0 every-time.

```
var pages_xml:XML = XML(httpservice.lastResult);
Alert.show(pages_xml.page.images.image.length());
```

can anybody help?. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is some problem with your response, please check it, because the code to show the number of children is perfectly OK.

Comment: i'm using the same response data somewhere else

Comment: Did you check the "pages_xml" variable in watch expression? Check the XML is proper or not. I mean "page_xml" should have value as

Comment: <pages>
    <page>
        <user>1</user>
        <name>book1</name>
        <theme>mariage</theme>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>25</height>
        <images>
            <image>image1.jpg</image>
            <image>image2.jpg</image>
            <image>image3.jpg</image>
            <image>image4.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </page>
</pages>

Comment: i'm using the same response data somewhere else and it's working perfectly. i can get the user , the name, the theme .. , and i can event get the image url if i use `code`pages_xml.page.images.image[0]`code`.
so i don't think it's about the response.

Comment: ok, check for Alert.show((pages_xml.page.images.image.length()).toString());

Comment: it shows 0 as a result;
and if i try `code` Alert.show(pages_xml.toString());`code` it shows [object:Object]

Comment: I tried it here, I am getting response as 4,  I used <pages>
    <page>
        <user>1</user>
        <name>book1</name>
        <theme>mariage</theme>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>25</height>
        <images>
            <image>image1.jpg</image>
            <image>image2.jpg</image>
            <image>image3.jpg</image>
            <image>image4.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </page>
</pages>    as XML and code snippet as Alert.show((pages_xml.page.images.image.length()).toString());    I am getting proper response

Comment: i'm going to check up the whole thing and see, thank you for your time anyway

Comment: did you try Alert.show(pages_xml.toString());
i just want to know if it's normal to get [object:Object] as a result in this case.

Comment: it worked,
i've tried to use the httpservice response directly without passing it to the xml variable (without conversion).

Alert.show(httpservice.lastResult.pages.page.images.image.length);
N.B:length without "()"

Comment: ohh ok, I thought there would be problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

the following code worked fine.

```
Alert.show(httpservice.lastResult.pages.page.images.image.length);
```